# Why does Laravel fail to create a model relation?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a relationship between models in laravel, but it seems to be failing for some reason.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'userType'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    //classes created by user;
    public function classes() {
        return $this->hasMany(userOwnedClass::class, 'ownerId');
    }
}
class userOwnedClass extends Model { 
    protected $table = 'classes'; 
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'archived', 'ownerId']; 
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function owner() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'ownerId');
    }
}
```

The database structure of `users` is laid out here:

```
class Users extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->enum('userType', ['student', 'teacher']);
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

The database structure for classes is laid out here:

```
class Classes extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->boolean('archived')->default(0);
            $table->integer('ownerId')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('ownerId')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('classes');
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to class the `owner()` method on an instance of `userOwnedClass`, I receive an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo` object rather than an instance of User. Can anyone identify the error?

Comment: can you show the database structure for both tables

Comment: I edited the post to include relevant excerpts from the database migration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `owner` as an attribute not a method.

```
$userOwnedClass->owner;
```

When you call `owner()` method, you'll get an instance of eloquent relation to perform extra queries on that model.

If you call the function owner(), you can get the id of the owner by

```
$userOwnedClass->owner()->id;
```